# Language choser

Tags: laravel-5.1

I want to make a Language chooser in Laravel 5.1, but i know how I can make it, but I want that it remembers the selected language (so if I visit the page again, that I have still the samen language). But how can I do it? And have I need to store it in the DB?

Better explained here:

So if a visitor joins the site for the first time, then the language will be "English" and then he can choose his language that he/she want's. If the same person leaves and joins at another time, then the language would be the same as the person selected earlier.

Comment: Have you tried thinking about cookies? Just like in Laravel 4.2?

Answer (score 0):

I’ve written a blog post about this, see [Detect and change language on the fly with Laravel](http://www.glutendesign.com/posts/detect-and-change-language-on-the-fly-with-laravel) for details but basically you need a Middleware to attribute a default locale:

```
/**
 *
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Session::has('locale')) {
        $locale = Session::get('locale', Config::get('app.locale'));
    } else {
        $locale = substr($request->server('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'), 0, 2);

        if ($locale != 'fr' && $locale != 'en') {
            $locale = 'en';
        }
    }

    App::setLocale($locale);

    return $next($request);
}
```

And a method (along with a form) to store a language change:

```
/**
 * Change session locale
 * @param  Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function changeLocale(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, ['locale' => 'required|in:fr,en']);

    \Session::put('locale', $request->locale);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```